This black spot/blob has been appearing in the middle of my display
This is a 3 week old AKASO Brave 4 and it suddenly displays this very noticeable black spot/blob around the middle of the display. The camera was perfectly fine when I last used it and the next time I went to film something there it is.
I suspect lens dust or sensor damage but couldn't find much information about the cause or any solutions. So far I reached out to the company's customer service portal half a week ago without any resolution.
The spot floats moves around when recording with stabilisation on, and stays in one spot with stabilisation off or when not recording. Gently wiping the lens with a microfiber cloth doesn't seem to do anything
One thing I am concerned about is if using the camera to film under hot and humid conditions (in bright sunlight) for around 10 minutes or more at a time (35ºC) would have contributed to this, or would it normally be fine to do so when it comes to action cameras like these?



Was the sun in the frame at the spot in question when you were filming for about ten minutes?

Those recordings were done on a moving vehicle (bike) in a location with moderately intense sunlight, although I'm pretty sure that would still count as direct exposure to sunlight

Given the shape... it looks like an out of focus 'bug' of some description. Is it possible something got into the housing?

Was it placed on the ground/lawn that day, I'm inclined to think it is a small ant that invaded/was ingested into the camera works, so probably someone with digital camera cleaning experience, steady hands, sure eyes and the weeny tool set to perform the operation. Much luck.

@sagaris I'm not asking if the day was a bright one. I'm asking if the sun was actually inside the frame where the camera was pointed? If so, did the camera stay pointed so that the sun was in the same spot within the frame for several minutes?

@MichaelC Oh, I should've clarified that when I replayed my clips the sun itself were generally not visible throughout the majority of them, and any direct exposure I did see were very brief (<1 minute). Hope that clears up any confusion

Nothing you did could have caused this.
It's moving when stabilization is enabled because stabilization moves the image frame on the sensor (it's digital, it crops image dynamically). If stabilization was done by lens or sensor shift the blob wouldn't have moved.
This is definitely debris stuck on the sensor which got there during assembly. If you cannot gently shake it off you will need to ask the seller to fix it (either by servicing it or replacing it).
P.S.: I've never seen images from sensor damaged by heat but for it to happen the sun should necessarily be in that position on the image (you are better to judge it but the sun is unlikely to be in that place on the image). Plus the lens being slow and short (image of the sun won't be too bright and won't be too large) further reduces probability of the damage. And finally you can try checking out the manual which might address whether having sun in the image is fine.

Because this is a sealed/waterproof action camera I agree that this is some type of internal contamination due to manufacturing flaw; the camera should be repaired/replaced under warranty.

If the camera was pointed directly at the sun for long enough, the sensor could have actually been damaged by the sun.

@MichaelC "Those recordings were done on a moving vehicle"

@EuriPinhollow the question includes statement about filming in bright sunlight for around 10 minutes, and comment you referring to contains "I'm pretty sure that would still count as direct exposure to sunlight" The fact it was a moving vehicle is mostly irrelevant, sun is approximately stationary in the frame if you keep camera still to the car and drive straight at such slow speeds as cars do. You need a plane or a rocket for the speed movement to matter.

@EuriPinhollow You can't see the sun from a moving vehicle? I often have to drive towards the late afternoon sun in a moving vehicle and it nearly burns my eyeballs out.
